As a foreigner, must I fill a W-9 just because I have an SSN from my time working in the US?
I was a resident alien of USA for tax purposes for 5 years until 2023. I have SSN. I moved out of USA to Canada in 2023. I am a nonresident of USA since January 2024.
In January 2024, I got a job in Canada from a US public company which granted me RSUs. I completed form W8-BEN (foreign status) with the stock provider (E*TRADE).
When I reported to E*TRADE that I have SSN too because I lived and worked in USA for many years, they told me that I need to complete form W-9. Since I no longer live in USA, I think I should only complete form W8-BEN.
Question: Any suggestions on which form I should complete?
I will also talk to a tax professional to re-confirm the discussion here.

After I edited the title, the related section popped up a nearly identical question. I'll close as dup.
